# MySQL self join query?

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, pivot-table, self-join

i have a table that looks like:

```
-------------------------------------
col0 | col1 | col2 | .......| col10 |
-------------------------------------
1    | A    | 2.5  | .......| 4.5   |
-------------------------------------
2    | A    | 3.5  | .......| 5.5   |
-------------------------------------
3    | A    | 4.5  | .......| 6.5   |
-------------------------------------
1    | B    | 2.5  | .......| 4.5   |
-------------------------------------
2    | B    | 3.5  | .......| 5.5   |
-------------------------------------
3    | B    | 4.5  | .......| 6.5   |
-------------------------------------
1    | C    | 2.5  | .......| 4.5   |
-------------------------------------
2    | C    | 3.5  | .......| 5.5   |
-------------------------------------
```

I want to run a SQL Query that output a table like this:

```
col0 |  A  | B   |
------------------
1    | 2.5 | 2.5 |
------------------
2    | 3.5 | 3.5 |
------------------
3    | 4.5 | 4.5 |
```

this is what i have tried:

```
select table_a.col0,
table_a.col2 as "A" where table_a.col1="A",
table_b.col2 as "B" where table_b.col1="B"
from table as table_a inner join table as table_b
on table_a.col0=table_b.col0
```

and

```
select table_a.col0,
table_a.col2 as "A" where table_a.col1="A",
table_b.col2 as "B"
from table as table_a inner join table as table_b
on table_a.col0=table_b.col0 where table_b.col1="B";
```

I have a tried a lot of different queries in that order to solve the syntax error still no luck. New to SQL, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do conditional aggregation to pivot your dataset:

```
select
    col0,
    max(case when col1 = 'A' then col2 end) A,
    max(case when col1 = 'B' then col2 end) B
from mytable
where col1 in ('A', 'B')
group by col0
```

The query groups together rows that have the same value in `col0`; then, the conditional expressions in the `select` clause pick the values corresponding to  `A` and `B` rows.

Comment: what would you suggest if i wanted to group rows with an arbitrary number of values, is possible for a similar case but say for example the rows have 'A' to 'Z' values?